# cakePHP login fails

Tags: php, cakephp

I am just start coding with cakePHP. I coded around and tried to write a login and authentication page. 
I tried this:

```
class AppController extends Controller 
{
    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        if ($this->request->action != 'login' && !$this->Session->check('profile')) 
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('You are not logged in');
            $this->redirect(array(
                'controller' => 'profiles',
                'action' => 'login'
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that i cannot login. I always get

> "You are not logged in"

Without this code, it works but didn't protec the other pages.
My routes.php

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'profiles', 'action' => 'login'));
```

My ProfilesController.php

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) 
    {
        $profile = $this->Profile->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'name' => $this->request->data('Profile.name'),
                'password' => $this->request->data('Profile.password')
            )
        ));
        if ($profile) 
        {
            $this->Session->write('Profile',$profile);
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Projects',
                'action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Session->setFlash('Profile and Password does not match!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you aren't loading the auth component and you aren't actually logging in the user.

You might want to consider the builtin authentication functions before trying to make your own.

Documentation on authentication.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html

Tutorial to learn about Cake authentication. It is pretty simple.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html